Massive increase in GA4 sessions without increase in users or page views
On 4th November, something odd happened in our GA4 account - sessions jumped enormously, from all sources (except Direct):
GA4 chart showing huge jump in sessions on 4th Nov
At the same time, revenue attributed to Direct traffic has dropped to zero most days and organic revenue increased. The Users metric dropped almost 25% at the same time (Users from Direct dropped more like 50%).
Nothing has been done to the site around this period (no changes or updates - it's a WordPress/WooCommerce site) and no changes have been made in Tag Manager or in GA4 settings.
Also notable - page views did not increase, but Direct traffic page views fell to <100/day from >1000, whilst organic page views more than doubled. Same is true for the session_start event (i.e. no more total sessions began, despite the number of sessions massively increasing overnight!)
I see that attribution to Paid Search also goes up, but not by as much as Organic. Cross-network traffic level is reported as much more erratic from 4th Nov onwards.
I'm at a loss to explain why this happened or how to fix it! Can anyone help please?
